# where we can place crossdomain.xml

Tags: crossdomain.xml

Hi I have deployed my flex application on application(_http://myserver:11090/apps) and using proxy server (web server - _https://mysite.site.com) which redirect to application server.

But at run time application search crossdomain.xml at the location _http://myserver:11090/crossdomain.xml due to this it gives popup "Authentication required" for JBoss and ask credentials of app server.

can you please help me where I should place crossdomain.xml file on app server or web server's root directory.

right now crossdomain.xml is placed at the location _http://myserver:11090/apps/crossdomain.xml

Please help me. I am stuck due to this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the crossdomain.xml file in the root of your server, not in a subdirectory.  If you need help on how to configure JBoss or your proxy to allow this, I suggest you try https://serverfault.com/ :).

Answer (score 0):

Place crossdoamin.xml at webapps/ROOT folder Then it will work.