# where should keep crossdomain.xml

Tags: crossdomain.xml

where to place crossdomain.xml file. i am having secure web server which redirect to application server. Should i place it under root directory of web server or under root directory of application server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where we can place crossdomain.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101770/where-we-can-place-crossdomain-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Just place it in your root directory of domain you have to work with - http://[your.domain.or.subdomain]/crossdomain.xml