# How can you access a bucket file at a domain root with HTTPS on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: flash, google-cloud-storage, plupload

I need to have `crossdomain.xml` accessible at the root of a domain when accessing a Google Storage bucket.

The SSL cert doesn't work for http://storage.example.com.storage.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml, so is there any way to get GCS to work with cross-domain Flash uploads? Is there another domain I can securely reach my bucket at, where my files are at the root?

This was simple when I could use a CNAME with our bucket when using HTTP, but you can't use a CNAME with HTTPS.

Previously was uploading files to: 
 http://storage.example.com/ 
But now we are uploading to since we need SSL:
 https://storage.googleapis.com/storage.example.com/.

However, this is breaking cross-domain Flash uploads, because Flash now tries to validate the cross-origin policy at https://storage.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml which doesn't exist of course.

Comment: What does your Flash (AS3) code look like? You should show the line that accesses the URL for crossdomain.xml. Or better just edit it yourself and test...

Comment: PS: Also consider just adding a (modified) crossdomain.xml at the https location. **http** server and **https** server are like two different locations to Flash so they will not clash or anything. Modified meaning let it know to access https location URLs instead.

Comment: I didn't write the Flash code as it's part of the uploader library I'm using `plupload`. I did find the source, but I don't think that's my core issue here. This is mostly Google Storage specific because I'm not sure if there's a way to upload files to my bucket via HTTPS where my my files are at the root. This is necessary b/c Flash tries to fetch `crossdomain.xml` from the root of my bucket and it's my understanding that it has to be at the root (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101770/where-we-can-place-crossdomain-xml). Is there another URL path for GCS where my bucket is at the root?

Comment: Okay, first I mistook your Google storage for Amazon storage (which I have) so maybe their setup is different. Secondly it occured to me that usually crossdomain is for  the allowing of **downloading** of your data by some other server(s), so when a user is **uploading** a file from their computer they have already "agreed" in a way to allow access to that file and there is no need for crossdomain. I looked at the SWF source code and I dont see any coding for loading **crossdomain.xml** but there was a function to handle security errors which just prints the error type on-screen...

Comment: I think your problem is mixed-content related. Like is the HTML and embedded SWF both running from some **https** website? SWF must be in some **https** location itself to handle any file to/from other **https** locations. Or else update question with how one can try to re-create your problem. A link to see the problem in action might also

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that the main issue is that I need to expose `crossdomain.xml` (or any file) at the root of an HTTPS domain, where the bucket is hosted on GCS.

Comment: is the uploader SWF running from:  https://storage.googleapis.com/storage.example.com/pluploader.swf? and similarly the upload.html that displays that SWF? That could avoid across domains transfer issue (ie: does not need xml file). Is it really hard to make a test page so helpers can look at this in action & asess the problem? I think some S.O people are passing on cos they cant fix what they cant see. Alternativley if you have PHP installed just use a **[PHP-based uploader](https://goo.gl/5f5wSb)** since cant be guaranteed the I.E users have Flash installed anyways.

Comment: As a side note... on Amazon AWS I'm able to simply put crossdomain in a bucket and everything is fine. So how to recreate your problem? Do I make a bucket and use pluploader in a different domain like `http.. //..mysite` but send uploads to the bucket or should I use pluploader.swf also already in the `https` bucket? This is why we need link to see your problem/setup in action

Comment: The uploader swf is hosted on the site's domain with all the JS. Is Flash cross origin dependent on the swf location vs the site's location? If so, maybe that could be a workaround. What I was trying to do was more of a Google Cloud Storage issue to access my bucket securely at the root of a domain such as https://bucket/ or https://bucket.storage.googleapis.com/ instead of https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/. If I could do this (like you can on S3) everything would work.